# Restrições banco PostgreSQL em aplicação comercial

Tags: postgresql, conexão

Quais as restrições em utilizar banco de dados PostgreSQL em minha aplicação comercial em C#?

Qual o limite de tamanho?
E de conexões simultâneas? Que problemas que posso vir a enfrentar, em questão de conexão em rede com outas máquinas?

Comment: No meu entendimento esta pergunta é válida, tanto que já foi respondida. Engraçado como as pessoas votam para fechar por qualquer coisa, sem ao menos comentar com quem abriu a pergunta.

Comment: Concordo plenamente Flávio Granato. Eu acredito que se a pergunta foi feita, ou é duplicada como é o termo usado, é porque talvez não atingiu o objetivo de quem esta com duvida sobre o assunto. Tudo bem que existe uma série de regras sobre como fazer as perguntas, só que as vezes é uma pergunta tão simples que não necessita de tanta informação. É uma pena que isso acontece, acaba desmotivando as pessoas de usarem o Stackoverflow, tenho vários amigos e colegas que abandonaram por esse motivo.

Comment: A pergunta tem de ser tão funcional que a pessoa não precisa fazer a pergunta ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Restrições de licenciamento:**

Nenhuma, o código é aberto.

**Tamanho máximo para um banco de dados:**

ilimitado (existem bancos de dados de 32 TB)

**Tamanho máximo para uma tabela:**

32 TB

**Tamanho máximo de uma linha:**

1,6 TB

**Tamanho máximo para um campo:**

1 GB

**Número máximo de linhas em uma tabela:**

ilimitado

**Número máximo de colunas em uma tabela:**

250-1600, dependendo do tipos de coluna

**Número máximo de índices em uma tabela:**

ilimitado

**Número máximo de conexões:**

por padrão, 100 conexões simultâneas, mas pode ser configurado no postgresql.conf

Fonte: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/42C3C382.5020108%40cineca.it

Answer (score 4):

O licenciamento é tranquilo e pode fazer qualquer coisa.

Não há grandes restrições importantes, e pode rodar bem. Ou não. Porque geralmente o que mais faz diferença é a pessoa saber o que está fazendo, isso é muito mais difícil. Para a maioria das aplicações escolher alguma coisa que não seja o ideal é um problema menor. Até porque em geral a escolha errada é feita por desconhecimento geral e isso causará problema muito maior.

Estudar os fundamentos para conseguir avaliar todos os pontos é algo muito mais importe que saber algumas informações específicas. De que adianta saber quem descobriu o Brasil, se essa informação pode ser falsa, incompleta ou confusa, ou ainda ser irrelevante, ou não saber porque precisa saber disso?

Não há limitações de conexões no software a não ser por configuração. Claro que há um limite prático, mas depende de uma série de fatores. E isso não importa muito, porque em aplicações corporativas não chega nem perto e em aplicações web só chegará se foi tudo arquitetado errado.

O tamanho máximo de dados é teórico e não deve se preocupar, até porque se um fizer uma aplicação que precisa de tanto será um profissional que domina muito o assunto. Há limitações específicas que em quase tudo é teórico, novamente porque se ultrapassar está fazendo algo errado. Tudo tem solução. O mais importante limite é o número de colunas em uma tabela que é 250 em alguns casos, na prática o limite pode ser 1600 dependendo dos tipos usados, e se precisar mais que 250 tem grande chance de estar fazendo algo errado, e tem como contornar. Outro é o limite de 1GB por coluna, que é tranquilo pra quase tudo.

Tem uma [resposta no SO que ainda mantém os limites descritos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13639920/221800).

Não há limite de conexão de rede com outras máquinas, só bancos de dados não cliente-servidor é que possuem limitação nisso. Obviamente há um limite prático

A decisão de qual banco de dados usar e modelo adotado passa por outras coisas. Não é porque sabe disto que tomará a decisão certa de qual banco de dado usar.

Eu ia falar para sempre olhar na documentação para ver essas coisas, isso é o mais importante para saber o que fazer, mas neste caso específico tiraram, o que mostra que o produto começou ficar mais *marketeiro* e isso é um mal sinal, esse é um projeto que prezava muito pela engenharia.